# Javascript: Checking if multiple custom elements are defined via Promises

Tags: javascript, vaadin, web-component

Hopefully this has not been asked before - I've had a hard time figuring out how to word the question.

I'm playing around with Vaadin's date and time pickers - an example dealing with date ranges is shown here https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-date-picker/html-examples In that example, `customElements.whenDefined('vaadin-date-picker')...` is being used to ensure the elements exist.

I'm interested in combining the date picker with the time picker, essentially making a date/time range picker. Therefore, I would need to check that both `vaadin-date-picker` and `vaadin-time-picker` exist.

What is the 'correct' way or best practice to handle this combined check?

My first guess was:

```
customElements.whenDefined('vaadin-date-picker').whenDefined('vaadin-time-picker').then...
```

But there are no examples showing this approach - as far as I can tell - so I suspect it either is not correct, or simply an uncommon problem. I think a working solution would be

```
customElements.whenDefined('vaadin-date-picker').then(function() { 
  customElements.whenDefined('vaadin-time-picker').then(function() {
    // insert code here...
  });
});
```

but this seems quite inelegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use `Promise.all` to create one promise out of the two original ones:

```
Promise.all([
    customElements.whenDefined('vaadin-date-picker'),
    customElements.whenDefined('vaadin-time-picker')
  ]).then(function() {
  // Do something
});
```

Another alternative that is in a way even more elegant is to do everything in an `async` function. Then you can `await` each promise separately before continuing.

```
(async () => {
  await customElements.whenDefined('vaadin-date-picker');
  await customElements.whenDefined('vaadin-time-picker');
  // Do something
})();
```

If you're already inside a function that doesn't have to return anything immediately, then you can just mark that function as `async` instead of doing a dummy lambda wrapper like in my example.